# Javascript in my masterpage loads in Firefox but not IE

Tags: javascript, custom-masterpage, internet-explorer

In my masterpage, I've loaded a simple javascript file from `/_layouts/myfolder/myjs.js` - and the script loads and runs in Firefox (even in different instances and with different plugins) but not in IE 10, nor in Chrome.

The script is just this:

```
alert("bob");
```

The popup blocker is disabled, and Security Zone is set to low.  Javascript is enabled.

I've tried regular old js script links, and I've also tried the delayed loading, like this:

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="myScriptLink" runat="server" Name="/_layouts/mylib/myscript.js" LoadAfterUI="true" OnDemand="false"/>
```

What could cause this?

Comment: Have you cleared the browser cache?

Comment: Yes - I cleared everything.  The master loads - I can see the stylesheets working.

Comment: Could it be related to the security zone?

Comment: It's set to low. I'm using a Windows 7 Pro x64 virtual machine (the host is the same), and it's *not* https.  I'm logged in as domain and sp admin.

Comment: How are you making the script execute?

Comment: The script is just added via regular old script tags in the header of the master page.  It should just run when the page is opened (like it does in FF).  Funny - it doesn't load in Chrome either - just in FF (even skipping the cache).

Comment: Does it help if you wrap it in a method that you call from ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded or any other body onload event? Or is it just when it is unwrapped that it is not executed?

Comment: Ah, sorry fellas.  I'm a dunce.  I added the /* to comment out the script, but I didn't scroll down far enough to see that another comment cancelled the comment.  Which means it actually is working and there is something else wrong in the script.  I'm going to delete my question.  Thanks for helping.

Comment: Actually, I'm going to leave the post in case it helps anyone.  I found the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am used to coding in autohotkey where I can do this by way of optional parameters:

```
somefunction(parameter, optionalparam="aConstant"){
   ;some stuff
}
```

However you can't do it that way in Javascript.  Instead you do it like this:

```
function somefunction(parameter, otherparameter){
    if(!otherparameter)
         otherparamteter = something;
}
```

Apparently, Firefox will still run the parts of the script that haven't yet failed.  IE and Chrome both dump the entire script and don't do anything at all.  That means that an `alert("bob");` at the top of the script will *always* run in Firefox, even if part of the code below it is wrong - but in IE and Chrome, nothing happens.

Interesting!

Answer (score 0):

Try to load jquery and fire alert inside ready function of Jquery and check.

Also, it can possible if you already added jquery in master page and something conflict on page load thats why not working in IE.

If possible, show me your head portion of master page.

Comment: The OP has already given the answer below